# Solution to System of Complicated Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I'm looking for a solution to this set of complicated differential equations:

$$\begin{align} \dfrac{dθ}{ds} & = \dfrac{\cos θ}{r} − z\\ \dfrac{dz}{ds}& = − \cos θ \\
\dfrac{dr}{ds} &= \sin θ \end{align}$$

Ideally, the solutions would be in the forms $θ(s)$, $z(s)$, and $r(s)$.

Does such a solution exist? If so, what is it?

Comment: Are you sure this problem is written correctly? What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: Are those derivatives supposed to be with respect to $s$? Or $t$? Or $\theta$? Or $z$? Or $r$? It makes a HUGE difference for the answer.

Comment: This problem was _not_ initially written correctly. The final equations should be in the forms of θ(s), z(s), and r(s), not in terms of t. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @reidm : Obviously, the set of differential equations is the characteristic equations of a PDE. Can you write this PDE ?